# Get reference to injector inside Angular 2.X custom module?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-di, angular2-injection

How we can get a reference to dependency injector inside the application module ?

Here is the example code of the custom module. So how we can get reference to Angular DI (Dependency Injector) inside this class ?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApplication,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [MyApplication]
})
export class MyApplicationModule {
  constructor() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean this ?

```
export class MyApplicationModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
}
```

Comment: (Coming from `@angular/core` by the way)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for  :)!